# Moodle Multiple Choice Questions with 2 Parts

Tags: moodle

I want to create a multiple choice question with multiple parts using the moodle package in LaTeX:

This is the layout I want:

*This problem has 2 parts*

Part I

(A) Choice 1

(B) Choice 2

(C) Choice 3

(D) Choice 4

Part II

(A) Choice 1

(B) Choice 2

(C) Choice 3

(D) Choice 4

I can use \begin{cloze} \end{cloze} to create something like it, but it gives a dropdown menu for the choices instead of (A), (B), (C), (D).

Comment: I provided an answer, but I am not sure if it solves your problem, because you didn't provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that would have helped to focus the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are using `moodle.sty`, be sure to use [Matthieu's version](https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle/) because it is much more powerful and bug-free than the standard CTAN version. Then, you use a `cloze` question with `multi` questions specifying `vertical`:

(this example has to be compiled with `lualatex --shell-escape` for the correct management of figures and accented chars).

```latex
% vim: set spelllang=es,en:
%! TEX program = lualatex --shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{amstext}
\WarningFilter{moodle}{Cloze Multi Shuffling}% I hope it's all ok...
\usepackage[tikz, section
%    ,handout % to have a nice handout without answers
]{moodle}
\moodleset{penalty=0}
\usepackage[RPvoltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}\ctikzsetstyle{romano}
\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Name of the test}

    \begin{cloze}{EC PNP}
        Considera el siguiente circuito, que se supone bien polarizado:

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [pnp](Q){Q};
            \draw (Q.B) -- ++(-0.5,0) to[sV, l=$v_i$] ++(0,-2) node[tlground]{};
            \draw (Q.C) to[R] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){};
            \draw (Q.E) to[R] ++(0,2) node[vcc](VCC){};
            \draw (Q.E) to[C=$C_1$, *-o] ++(1.5,0) node[right]{$v_o$};
            \draw (Q.E) -- ++(-1,0) coordinate(tmp) to[C=$C_2$] (tmp|-VCC) node[vcc]{};
            \draw (Q.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(tmp) to[C=$C_3$] (tmp|-VEE) node[vee]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}


        \begin{multi}[vertical]
            El condensador $C_1$:
            \item* Es de baja
            \item[fraction=-50] es de alta
            \item[fraction=-50] no influye
            \item[fraction=0] \emph{respuesta en blanco}
        \end{multi}

        \begin{multi}[vertical]
            El condensador $C_2$:
            \item[fraction=-50] Es de baja
            \item* es de alta
            \item[fraction=-50] no influye
            \item[fraction=0] \emph{respuesta en blanco}
        \end{multi}

        \begin{multi}[vertical]
            El condensador $C_3$:
            \item[fraction=-50] Es de baja
            \item[fraction=-50] es de alta
            \item* no influye
            \item[fraction=0] \emph{respuesta en blanco}
        \end{multi}
    \end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Everything is working perfectly. You solved both of my problems: With [vertical] I can now enable ABCD; with the new style file, now I can print out the feedback. THANK YOU.

Comment: AFAIK, the numbering options have no effect in multichoice questions embedded in cloze environments.